# There is a bug with the bounty banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When a new bounty without a comment appears, the `add a comment` appears half over the grey banner background:

[image]

While not a bad bad bug, it is annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, which should be in the next 8 hours.